# Git for windows 2.35.2 can not add exception safe.directory

Tags: windows, git

I am using `git version 2.35.2.windows.1` on my win10.
My project is stored in my NAS running Ubuntu.
I set up an SMB remote disk using samba, and do all necessary work on win10.

After the 2.35 update, i got

```sh
fatal: unsafe repository ('//192.168.1.120/sambashare/x' is owned by someone else) To add an exception for this directory, call:

git config --global --add safe.directory //192.168.1.120/sambashare/x
```

And after i did as instructed, git threw a warning said:
`warning: encountered old-style '//192.168.1.120/sambashare/x' that should be '%(prefix)//192.168.1.120/x'`

I tried to tweak the directory string a little (like changing it to `Z://x`, `Z://192.168.1.120/x`, etc.), but that is of no avail.

my git config file looks like:
`[safe] directory = //192.168.1.120/sambashare/x` , and i am not quite sure what to do to fix this problem.

For now, i am doing all my git work via ssh.
Thx in advance for any potential solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. The prefix must include the trailing `/`. Literally like this: `%(prefix)/`.
2. Whether you must use hostname, IP address or FQDN **depends on how you mounted the network share**.

Run `net use` to list the exact remote paths of mounted shares.

### Working examples

If the network share was mounted as `\\123.123.123.123\repoA` run

```
git config --global --add safe.directory %(prefix)///123.123.123.123/repoA
```

If the network share was mounted as `\\servername\repoB` run

```
git config --global --add safe.directory %(prefix)///servername/repoB
```

If the network share was mounted as `\\servername.company.com\repoC` run

```
git config --global --add safe.directory %(prefix)///servername.company.com/repoC
```

Alternatively you can edit the config with `git config --global --edit` to the following

```
[safe]
    directory = %(prefix)///123.123.123.123/repoA
    directory = %(prefix)///servername/repoB
    directory = %(prefix)///servername.company.com/repoC
```

Comment: I just copy/pasted the git config command from within git bash and it works now. Please note; this must be per repo. You can probably just find your global .gitconfig file and duplicate the directory command for every subsequent repo you have to work with.

Answer (score 8):

That warning is specific to [`git-for-windows/git` path.c](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/blob/fa8edb885d7fa702a4378e419762a1f25c6df6db/path.c#L742-L746), for any path starting with `/`

Trying instead the [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#UNC) `\\192.168.1.120\sambashare\x` would result, as commente by the [OP LNseyJt2X-24UJ4r7KTL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13482206/lnseyjt2x-24uj4r7ktl), in:

```
fatal: bad config output.
```

> Input it via `git config` produce something like `\\\\192.168.1.120\\sambashare` in the config file, which is not recognized.

Correct form, as illustrated in [michaelosthege's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473230/michaelosthege) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71859164/6309) is adding `%(prefix)/` (not just `%(prefix)`) before the path:

```
%(prefix)///192.168.1.120/x
```

Or downgrade Git for Windows (if you *really* do not want to see this warning), since this message comes from the recent [commit 66a6bcf](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/66a6bcf83cf8523040e40cb630dca2c5b36f84c5) for v2.35.2.windows.1:

> ### `mingw`: deprecate old-style runtime-prefix handling in `interpolate_path()`
>
> On Windows, an absolute POSIX path needs to be turned into a Windows
> one.
>
> We used to interpret paths starting with a single `/` as relative
> to the runtime-prefix, but now these need to be prefixed with
> `%(prefix)/`.
> Let's warn for now, but still handle it.

Or *upgrade* to 2.5.3 (see below), and opt-out with `safe.directory=*`

---

This all comes from With Git 2.35.2 (Q1 2022):

See [commit 6e7ad1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e7ad1e4c22e7038975ba37c7413374fe566b064) (27 Nov 2021) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
See [commit 53ef17d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/53ef17d3ee0f7fcb151f428ee3bd736b8046825f), [commit 1f480d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f480d5127b746c2345701b86f7e15ecbd3377a3), [commit 4d0b43a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d0b43aa765a0056c88381eea862364c95e358ca), [commit 93fbff0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93fbff09eb8ed9e728a61623a15a53a46a762639), [commit 87ed4fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/87ed4fc046840706138d46e0033a009e74c3887a), [commit 303b876](https://github.com/git/git/commit/303b876f76c2caccc9a289c4f14a2b2d3850684e), [commit 9bcd7a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9bcd7a8ecac1c9196bc927647bd06c38ec1feabe), [commit 201b0c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/201b0c7af6cad52cf6f0cfc46bd48201a23f6224), [commit 44de39c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44de39c45c65134f4a6e02e7702a5db70a71041d), [commit 6a2381a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a2381a3e5176b8deb69c799ed2b600366d36d39), [commit cb95038](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb95038137e9e66fc6a6b4a0e8db62bcc521b709), [commit 2a9a586](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2a9a5862e516935149697f710f4fb00f14b7c40b), [commit 898225b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/898225ba0419f3a2fabdf11750a90031a838f3b3) (17 Mar 2022), [commit fdcad5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fdcad5a53e14bd397e4fa323e7fd0c3bf16dd373) (23 Mar 2022), and [commit 8959555](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8959555cee7ec045958f9b6dd62e541affb7e7d9), [commit bdc77d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdc77d1d685be9c10b88abb281a42bc620548595) (02 Mar 2022) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f1b50ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1b50ec6f85883c483b344442c69cd3d88b38380), 11 Apr 2022)</sup>

> ### [`setup_git_directory()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8959555cee7ec045958f9b6dd62e541affb7e7d9): add an owner check for the top-level directory
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> It poses a security risk to search for a git directory outside of the directories owned by the current user.
>
> For example, it is common e.g. in computer pools of educational institutes to have a "scratch" space: a mounted disk with plenty of space that is regularly swiped where any authenticated user can create a directory to do their work.
> Merely navigating to such a space with a Git-enabled `PS1` when there is a maliciously-crafted `/scratch/.git/` can lead to a compromised account.
>
> The same holds true in multi-user setups running Windows, as `C:\` is writable to every authenticated user by default.
>
> To plug this vulnerability, we stop Git from accepting top-level directories owned by someone other than the current user.
> We avoid looking at the ownership of each and every directories between the current and the top-level one (if there are any between) to avoid introducing a performance bottleneck.
>
> This new default behavior is obviously incompatible with the concept of shared repositories, where we expect the top-level directory to be owned by only one of its legitimate users.
> To re-enable that use case, we add support for adding exceptions from the new default behavior via the config setting `safe.directory`.
>
> The `safe.directory` config setting is only respected in the system and global configs, not from repository configs or via the command-line, and can have multiple values to allow for multiple shared repositories.
>
> We are particularly careful to provide a helpful message to any user trying to use a shared repository.

`config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8959555cee7ec045958f9b6dd62e541affb7e7d9/Documentation/config.txt#L441-L442):

> include::config/safe.txt[]

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8959555cee7ec045958f9b6dd62e541affb7e7d9/Documentation/config/safe.txt#L1-L21):

> ### `safe.directory`
>
> These config entries specify Git-tracked directories that are
> considered safe even if they are owned by someone other than the
> current user. By default, Git will refuse to even parse a Git
> config of a repository owned by someone else, let alone run its
> hooks, and this config setting allows users to specify exceptions,
> e.g. for intentionally shared repositories (see the `--shared`
> option in [`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init)).
>
> This is a multi-valued setting, i.e. you can add more than one directory
> via `git config --add`. To reset the list of safe directories (e.g. to
> override any such directories specified in the system config), add a
> `safe.directory` entry with an empty value.
>
> This config setting is only respected when specified in a system or global
> config, not when it is specified in a repository config or via the command
> line option `-c safe.directory=<path>`.
>
> The value of this setting is interpolated, i.e. `~/<path>` expands to a
> path relative to the home directory and `%(prefix)/<path>` expands to a
> path relative to Git's (runtime) prefix.

---

### CHANGES with 2.35.3 (Apr. 2022):

See [commit d516b2d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d516b2db0af2221bd6b13e7347abdcb5830b2829), [commit 2f0dde7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f0dde7852b7866bb044926f73334ff3fc30654b), [commit 1f65dd6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f65dd6ae635f77c588ac432cad1a299723d00d6), [commit 1530434](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15304344342b7c888f732d28f908890d874bcb0c), [commit 09f66d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09f66d65f87e0a547c186e4027368a826a965256), [commit 17083c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17083c79ae842b51d82518e2efe5281346acea0e) (13 Apr 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 0f85c4a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f85c4a30b072a26d74af8bbf63cc8f6a5dfc1b8), [commit e47363e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e47363e5a8bdf5144059d664c45c0975243ef05b) (13 Apr 2022) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
See [commit bb50ec3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb50ec3cc300eeff3aba7a2bea145aabdb477d31) (13 Apr 2022) by [Matheus Valadares (`Matheus28`)](https://github.com/Matheus28).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1ac7422](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ac7422e39b0043250b026f9988d0da24cb2cb58), 13 Apr 2022)</sup>

> ### [`setup`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f85c4a30b072a26d74af8bbf63cc8f6a5dfc1b8): opt-out of check with `safe.directory=*`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> With the addition of the safe.directory in [8959555](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8959555cee7ec045958f9b6dd62e541affb7e7d9) (`setup_git_directory()`: add an owner check for the top-level directory, 2022-03-02, Git v2.36.0-rc2 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1b50ec6f85883c483b344442c69cd3d88b38380)) `(setup_git_directory()`: add an owner check for the top-level directory, 2022-03-02) released in v2.35.2, we are receiving feedback from a variety of users about the feature.
>
> Some users have a very large list of shared repositories and find it cumbersome to add this config for every one of them.
>
> In a more difficult case, certain workflows involve running Git commands within containers.
> The container boundary prevents any global or system config from communicating `safe.directory` values from the host into the container.
> Further, the container almost always runs as a different user than the owner of the directory in the host.
>
> To simplify the reactions necessary for these users, extend the definition of the safe.directory config value to include a possible '*' value.
> This value implies that all directories are safe, providing a single setting to opt-out of this protection.
>
> Note that an empty assignment of safe.directory clears all previous values, and this is already the case with the "if (!value `||` !*value)" condition.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0f85c4a30b072a26d74af8bbf63cc8f6a5dfc1b8/Documentation/config/safe.txt#L22-L28):

> To completely opt-out of this security check, set `safe.directory` to the
> string `*`. This will allow all repositories to be treated as if their
> directory was listed in the `safe.directory` list. If `safe.directory=*`
> is set in system config and you want to re-enable this protection, then
> initialize your list with an empty value before listing the repositories
> that you deem safe.

---

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), `safe.directory` is further clarified.

See [commit 756d159](https://github.com/git/git/commit/756d15923bf6806f94484054873e284728a89c4b), [commit 424f315](https://github.com/git/git/commit/424f315d9f15338ee950f343e01becd6f087121b), [commit f625639](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f62563988fefed73d795cfaeae203421b784c334) (27 Apr 2022) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1256a25](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1256a25ecd5df8fb418a537d856bf442da984c17), 20 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`safe.directory`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/756d15923bf6806f94484054873e284728a89c4b): document and check that it's ignored in the environment
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>

> The description of 'safe.directory' mentions that it's respected in the system and global configs, and ignored in the repository config and on the command line, but it doesn't mention whether it's respected or ignored when specified via environment variables (nor does the commit message adding 'safe.directory' from [commit 8959555](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8959555cee7ec045958f9b6dd62e541affb7e7d9) (`setup_git_directory()`: add an owner check for the top-level directory, 2022-03-02, Git v2.36.0-rc2 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1b50ec6f85883c483b344442c69cd3d88b38380))).
>
> Clarify that 'safe.directory' is ignored when specified in the environment, and add tests to make sure that it remains so.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/756d15923bf6806f94484054873e284728a89c4b/Documentation/config/safe.txt#L16-L17):

> config, not when it is specified in a repository config, via the command
> line option `-c safe.directory=<path>`, **or in environment variables**.

---

With a recent update to refuse access to repositories of other people by default, "`sudo make install`" and "[`sudo git describe`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2088a0c0cd61ab6c98064e68619e1d931a4619e2/Documentation/git-describe.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe))</sup> stopped working.
This series intends to loosen it while keeping the safety with Git 2.37 (Q3 2022).

See [commit b9063af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9063afda17a2aa6310423c9f7b776c41f753091), [commit ae9abbb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae9abbb63eea74441e3e8b153dc6ec1f94c373b4), [commit 5f1a3fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f1a3fec8c304decaa9af2bf503712050a4a84e0) (12 May 2022) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2088a0c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2088a0c0cd61ab6c98064e68619e1d931a4619e2), 26 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`git-compat-util`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae9abbb63eea74441e3e8b153dc6ec1f94c373b4): avoid failing dir ownership checks if running privileged
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Guy Maurel</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Randall Becker</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>

> [bdc77d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdc77d1d685be9c10b88abb281a42bc620548595) ("Add a function to determine whether a path is owned by the current user", 2022-03-02, Git v2.36.0-rc2 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1b50ec6f85883c483b344442c69cd3d88b38380)) checks for the effective uid of the running process using `geteuid()`, but didn't account for cases where that user was root (because `git` was invoked through `sudo` or a compatible tool) and the original `uid` that repository trusted for its config was no longer known, therefore failing the following otherwise safe call:
>
> ```
> guy@renard ~/Software/uncrustify $ sudo git describe --always --dirty
> [sudo] password for guy:
> fatal: unsafe repository ('/home/guy/Software/uncrustify' is owned by someone else)
> ```
>
> Attempt to detect those cases by using the environment variables that those tools create to keep track of the original user id, and do the ownership check using that instead.
>
> This assumes the environment the user is running on after going privileged can't be tampered with, and also adds code to restrict that the new behavior only applies if running as `root`, therefore keeping the most common case, which runs unprivileged, from changing, but because of that, it will miss cases where `sudo` (or an equivalent) was used to change to another unprivileged user or where the equivalent tool used to raise privileges didn't track the original id in a `sudo` compatible way.
>
> Because of compatibility with `sudo`, the code assumes that `uid_t` is an unsigned integer type (which is not required by the standard) but is used that way in their codebase to generate `SUDO_UID`.
> In systems where `uid_t` is signed, `sudo` might be also patched to NOT be unsigned and that might be able to trigger an edge case and a bug (as described in the code), but it is considered unlikely to happen and even if it does, the code would just mostly fail safely, so there was no attempt either to detect it or prevent it by the code, which is something that might change in the future, based on expected user feedback.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ae9abbb63eea74441e3e8b153dc6ec1f94c373b4/Documentation/config/safe.txt#L29-L41):

> As explained, Git only allows you to access repositories owned by
> yourself, i.e. the user who is running Git, by default.
> When Git
> is running as '`root`' in a non Windows platform that provides `sudo`,
> however, `git` checks the `SUDO_UID` environment variable that `sudo` creates
> and will allow access to the `uid` recorded as its value instead.
> This is to make it easy to perform a common sequence during installation
> "`make && sudo make install`".
> A git process running under '`sudo`' runs as '`root`' but the '`sudo`' command exports the environment variable to record
> which id the original user has.
> If that is not what you would prefer and want `git` to only trust
> repositories that are owned by `root` instead, then you must remove
> the `SUDO_UID` variable from `root`'s environment before invoking `git`.

And:

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), `sudo git foo` used to consider a repository owned by the original user a safe one to access; it now also considers a repository owned by root a safe one, too (after all, if an attacker can craft a malicious repository owned by root, the box is 0wned already).

See [commit 6b11e3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b11e3d52e919cce91011f4f9025e6f4b61375f2) (17 Jun 2022) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 694c0cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/694c0cc0fb531b17750ac6e81920054f193f8eb8), 17 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`git-compat-util`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b11e3d52e919cce91011f4f9025e6f4b61375f2): allow root to access both `SUDO_UID` and root owned
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Johanness Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>

> Previous changes introduced a regression which will prevent root for accessing repositories owned by thyself if using `sudo` because `SUDO_UID` takes precedence.
>
> Loosen that restriction by allowing root to access repositories owned by both uid by default and without having to add a safe.directory exception.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6b11e3d52e919cce91011f4f9025e6f4b61375f2/Documentation/config/safe.txt#L33-L35):

> however, git checks the `SUDO_UID` environment variable that `sudo` creates and will allow access to the uid recorded as its value in addition to the id from 'root'.

Comment: write UNC path directly in `gitconfig` results in a `fatal: bad config` output. Input it via `git config` produce something like `\\\\192.168.1.120\\sambashare` in the config file, which is not recognized. Literally putting a `%(prefix)/` (not `%(prefix)`) before `//192.168.1.120/x`solves the problem. :D

Comment: @LNseyJt2X-24UJ4r7KTL Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer to make that clearer, and added the latest from Git 2.35.3, released this morning.

Answer (score 0):

I am using git version 2.42.0 in Windows within Spyder, and I am working on a repository on my network drive. I have to work with a lot of different window users in my environment, so I am constantly having to fight with the unsafe directory problem.

I would get the following error:

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at ...
```

I would enter the exact recommended command from git, and then I would get a second error about the wrong number of arguments.

Here is the recommended command I would get:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///filer/gitprojectfolder'
```

And the error:

```
error: wrong number of arguments, should be 2
```

I finally tried looking at the git global config file manually using the following command in Git Bash.

```
notepad ~/.gitconfig
```

If this doesn't work, you can use `git config --global --edit` to open the global configuration file. Mine was located at `c:\users\username\.gitconfig`.

This opens up the global config file in Notepad. Here I copied the `recentrepo` value to the `[safe]` area. Note that quotation marks are not required for file paths with spaces.

```
[safe]

    directory = //filer/gitprojectfolder
```

Tada! Now the directory is accepted as safe.