# Getting error "fatal: unsafe repository" even though I AM the owner of it

Tags: git, repository

Before asking this here, I put some thinking into it, and maybe that happens because I added another SSH key to my profile.

I saw this error when I did `git status` in a repository that I have created before I add another SSH key.

So, what can I do to tell "it" that I am the owner of the repository?

The prompt, in case it is needed:

```
$ git status
fatal: unsafe repository ('C:/Users/#####/Desktop/workspace/DIO/Anotacoes' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory C:/Users/#####/Desktop/workspace/DIO/Anotacoes
```

Comment: Windows Git uses a [Windows "Security Identifier"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier) to decide whether you're the owner of a directory. You'll need to arrange for the SID on that directory to match your SID, or to put the above path into `safe.directory` (or to put `*` into `safe.directory` if you don't mind living dangerously).

Comment: Note that it's not necessarily a question of who owns the *repository*. It's about the SID numbers on the various directories. As a special case, your home directory is assumed to be "yours" even though (per the Git source code at least) it has an admin SID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> maybe that happens because I added another SSH key to my profile.

It should not be linked to SSH at all.
An SSH key is used to identify you on the *remote* server.
Your error message is because [Git stops from accepting top-level directories owned by someone other than the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71853288/6309).
Contexte: [CVE-2022-24765](https://github.blog/2022-04-12-git-security-vulnerability-announced/)

You can define the [`GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES` environment variable](https://git-scm.com/docs/git/2.35.2#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITCEILINGDIRECTORIEScode) to include your `C:/Users/#####/Desktop/workspace/DIO/Anotacoes` folder.

Comment: ok, I'll try to do it