# git error "[my repository] is on a file system that does not record ownership"

Tags: git, vpn, file-ownership

I'm getting this error between two W10 systems running a VPN and RDP.
My local system "`My`" has an area `c:\cap2office` that is a Git repository.
The remote system "Remote" has My C: drive mapped to its drive S:
I can see the `C:\cap2office directory` as `S:\cap2office` on the remote system.
And the username on the remote system is different from the username on my local system.

On Remote, I typed "`git status`" and it complained about mismatching ownership and suggested defining `GIT_TEST_DEBUG_UNSAFE_DIRECTORIES=true`, so I did that on the Remote system and that warning went away.

But it still says:

```
warning: '//tsclient/C/cap2office' is on a file system that does not record ownership
fatal: unsafe repository ('//tsclient/C/cap2office' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:
        git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///tsclient/C/cap2office'
```

So on the Remote system, I did:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory S:/cap2office
```

On the Remote, I can do `git config --list`

And in addition to the error (3 times):

```
   warning: '//tsclient/C/cap2office' is on a file system that does not record ownership
I see this at the end, so the safe.directory did get added:
    safe.directory=S:/cap2office
```

But when I do 'git status', I still get:

```
warning: '//tsclient/C/cap2office' is on a file system that does not record ownership
fatal: unsafe repository ('//tsclient/C/cap2office' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:
        git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///tsclient/C/cap2office'
```

So I also tried

```
git config --global --add safe.directory //tsclient/C/cap2office
warning: '//tsclient/C/cap2office' is on a file system that does not record ownership
warning: encountered old-style '//tsclient/C/cap2office' that should be '%(prefix)///tsclient/C/cap2office'
fatal: unsafe repository ('//tsclient/C/cap2office' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:
        git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///tsclient/C/cap2office'
```

Any ideas? What should `%prefix` be, maybe the drive mapping doesn't work?

BTW, I'm curious where the `.gitconfig` file is located.
It doesn't appear to be `C:\user\accountname\.gitconfig` as advertised or under the program files Git area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What should `%prefix` be, maybe the drive mapping doesn't work?

Actually, as I [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71853288/6309), you must use the actual string `%(prefix)`

> The value of this setting is interpolated, i.e.
>
> - `~/<path>` expands to a path relative to the home directory and
> - `%(prefix)/<path>` expands to a path relative to Git's (runtime) prefix.

And:

> I'm curious where the .gitconfig file is located.

Do a `git config --show-scope --show-origin -l`: you will see all the config files and their path.

Comment: You are incredibly helpful! Thank you!
It works, tho I still get a warning, is there a way to turn off the warning?

   warning: '//tsclient/c/cap2office' is on a file system that does not record ownership